# Print Dynamically created table by Rotativa

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am successfully creating dynamic table list using JSON with the stored procedure. Now I need to Print that Dynamically created a list of table using Rotativa.
Here is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult Merit(int Students)
    {
       ...
       ...
            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I tried something like :

```
public ActionResult MeritListToPSD()
    {
        return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("Merit");
    }
```

but it gives the error of "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Students' of nonnullable type"

Please Help If You Have Any Idea

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ActionResult MeritListToPSD()
{
    return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("Merit", new {students = students});
}
```

you have to pass in the student parameter to the Merit controller action when invoking the Merit action from rotativa.